Postgresql Service Stopped Working After Changing DB Path
I'm trying to move my postgres database on my Windows 10 machine from one location on the hard disk to another.
I've done what I think is needed

stopped the service
changed the service parameters so that the Properties on the service now shows the correct new path to the database
copied the whole database (the 'data' file and all its subfolders) to the new location.

But now when I start the service, it fails:

What have I done wrong?

Add --log=filename the same way you altered the --pgdata=datadir to tell it to print the log in a location it has access to, try again and read the log - it should say why it refuses to start. Depending on your config, it might've already sent that to the event viewer. My bet would be the service doesn't have access (ownership, permissions) to the copied data files in their new location.
